# Failed to install latest cocoapods version

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, cocoapods

i am building a flutter project and i need cocoapods version 1.9.0 and above, the following does not work for me,

> sudo gem install cocoapods

So i used this:

> brew install cocoapods

The above command installs version 1.5.2 and yet i need the latest.  At some point i used the command:

> sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4

but that only installs version 1.8.4 and doesnt work for any later ones. How do i install cocoapods version 1.10.0 on MacOs Catalina 10.15.7 with xcode installed.

This is the error i get when i run sudo gem install cocoapods:

> Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
> installing cocoapods:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/ext/ffi_c
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210326-11779-qtgmlh.rb
> extconf.rb checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not
> create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
> You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
> --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
> --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
> --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
> --with-ffi_c-dir    --without-ffi_c-dir     --with-ffi_c-include
> --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include    --with-ffi_c-lib
> --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib    --enable-system-libffi
> --disable-system-libffi     --with-libffi-config
> --without-libffi-config     --with-pkg-config   --without-pkg-config
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in
> `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` block in try_compile'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in
> `with_werror'     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` try_compile'     from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in
> `block in have_header'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'   from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> `block in postpone'   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in
> `postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'    from
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in
> `have_header'     from extconf.rb:10:in` system_libffi_usable?'   from
> extconf.rb:42:in `'
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
> which can be found here:
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0 for inspection. Results
> logged to
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/gem_make.out

Comment: what is the error running `sudo gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: @Raptor, i have edited the question with the error.

Comment: The fact that you have to say sudo is the problem.

Comment: @matt, what do you mean

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/

Comment: Thank you very much @matt, that link helped me alot